# JS: sort array by two fields

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

Now I have such code:

```
    sortArticles = (someArray) => {
        const result = [];

        let isValid = someArray.filter(item => item.isValid);
        let isInvalid = someArray.filter(item => !item.isValid);

        valid = funcSortArrayOfObjByKey(arrayChecked, 'article');
        invalid = funcSortArrayOfObjByKey(arrayUnchecked, 'article');
        // funcSortArrayOfObjByKey - is a function to sort, a kind of lodash implementation without unnecessary dependency 

        return result.concat(valid).concat(invalid);
    }
```

and I want to sort such array:

```
[
    {
        article: 'Some New Zarticle',
        isValid: false
    },
    {
        article: 'Some New Article',
        isValid: false
    },
    {
        article: 'Some New Zzarticle',
        isValid: true
    },
]
```

as result I want to see such array:

```
[
    {
        article: 'Some New Zzarticle',
        isValid: true
    },
    {
        article: 'Some New Article',
        isValid: false
    },
    {
        article: 'Some New Zarticle',
        isValid: false
    },
]
```

So: I need to have some kind of two arrays: first one, and second one (one with 'isValid', other without) and both of them should be sorted by 'article'. Is this possible to do somehow?
I tried also this way:

```
someArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.isValid === b.isValid) {
    return b.isValid - a.isValid;
  } else {
    return a.article.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.article.toLowerCase());
  }
})
```

but it's not working as I want it...

Comment: Notice that your `sortArticles()` function creates a new array while `someArray.sort()` mutates the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branches are inverted:

```
someArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.isValid != b.isValid) {
//              ^^
    return b.isValid - a.isValid;
  } else {
    return a.article.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' });
  }
})
```

Comment: it won't work if, for example one of objects don't has this field (undefined) - how to deal then?

Comment: @brabertaser19 Uh, you didn't say anything about that in the question? Which field can be missing, and how do you want to treat it?

Comment: @brabertaser19 Of course the easiest way to fix it would be to keep your objects valid at all times, and simply add the field before sorting.

Comment: isValid for example can be undefined (sure, normally it's not going to happen... but)

Comment: @brabertaser19 But what? Make it to never happen. If you want the sort to handle `isValid` values other than `true` and `false`, you will need to adjust the sort to do it explicitly.

Comment: but - means that I'm not sure that true/false will always be there, even after 10 years, when server-response will change...

Comment: @brabertaser19 When the server response changes arbitrarily, *all* of your app could break. It's not something you could guard against. Or if you insist, put a validation layer around the API service that throws a descriptive error message when the served format changes unexpectedly. But this validation should not go in the sorting functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this method to sort your array based on isValid then article.

```
someArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.isValid === b.isValid) {
        return a.article.localeCompare(b.article);
    } else {
        return (a.isValid) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```